# Disable Numlock notification

Tags: notifications

On my HP Elitebook 8570W I always get the notifications about chaning NumLock status. This is especially annoying when switching between VMs and the host.

[image: Numlock Notification Screenshot]

I have tried:

- There is no tray icon which has options to influence this behavior. Also no hidden ones
- There is no tab in Control Panel / Keyboard
- There is no other item (e.g. HP specific) in Control Panel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Hewlett-Packard\HP HotKey Support
```

Create any of the values listed to disable the notification you no longer want/need:

```
AmbientLightSensorOSD DWORD 0 
BrightnessOSD DWORD 0 
CapsLockOSD   DWORD 0 
NumLockOSD    DWORD 0 
ScrollLockOSD DWORD 0
VolumeOSD     DWORD 0
```

More info can be found in HP support doc [c03462568](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/action.process/public/kb/docDisplay/?javax.portlet.action=true&spf_p.tpst=kbDocDisplay&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&spf_p.prp_kbDocDisplay=wsrp-interactionState%3DdocId%253DZW1yX25hLWMwMzQ2MjU2OA%2525253D%2525253DhPsCeNc%257CdocLocale%253Den_US%257CcalledBy%253DSearch_Result&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken).

Comment: The simplest solution I've seen and it worked for me, thank you! That link appears to be dead, though.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and dragging the crosshair over the notification window, you can find:

- The program started when pressing NumLock is `hpCaslNotification.exe` from `%Program Files (x86)%\Hewlett-Packard\Shared`
- The parent process is `QLBController.exe` from `%Program Files (x86)%\Hewlett-Packard\HP Hotkey Support`

Using [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) you find that `QLBController.exe` is started from Registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

So there are the following options:

- You can rename `hpCaslNotification.exe` so that it cannot be started any more. This will prevent notification from being displayed.
- To temporarily disable the notifications, you can kill `QLBController.exe` in Process Explorer.
- To permanently prevent `QLBController.exe` from running, delete the Registry entry or removing the checkmark in Autoruns.